# 'Failed to get available update data" behind a proxy

Tags: 8

I am running Drupal 8.1.2 behind proxy in Ubuntu 16.04. There is an error:

```
Failed to get available update data for one project.
```

even the following is added in `settings.ini`:

```
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['http'] = '192.168.1.8:3128';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['https'] = '192.168.1.8:3128';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['no'] = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost'];
```

I tried both `192.168.1.8:3128` and `http://192.168.1.8:3128/` and neither works.

Both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` work well in bash though.

How can I fix the error?

Update, with screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The error is _for one project_ ...maybe you just have a custom/contrib module with dodgy packaging info and the proxy is actually working?

Comment: It's more than one project. I update the question with a screen shot.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't add any more information. That is still 1 project (drupal core) and all it's sub-modules. How many times have you tried running it? Sometimes a few may fail due to whatever networking related issues and then next time (or a couple of times later) they will work. If it always happens with the same project and it is reproducible every time you might have an issue.

Comment: The server is newly installed vanilla Drupal 8. It has been running for ~24 hours.

Comment: i have the same problem in D 8.4.2 behind corporate proxy. did u find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem on Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Drupal 8.5.6. This should also work for Ubuntu 16.04.4. Install php7.0-curl (or php-curl or php5-curl or php7.2-curl) and write `http://` before your proxy name (otherwise GuzzleHttp uses `tcp://`, I think).

## Console/SSH

```
sudo apt update
# Use php --version to find out what version of PHP you're on
sudo apt install php7.0-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

## Config

`/var/www/html/<DRUPALFOLDER>/sites/default/settings.php`

```
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['http'] = 'http://192.168.1.8:3128';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['https'] = 'http://192.168.1.8:3128';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['no'] = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost'];
```

### Optional

The old syntax is no longer necessary (but would not hurt either):

```
$settings['proxy_server'] = '192.168.1.8';  // HERE WITHOUT http:// !!!
$settings['proxy_port'] = 3128;
$settings['proxy_username'] = '';
$settings['proxy_password'] = '';
$settings['proxy_user_agent'] = '';
$settings['proxy_exceptions'] = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');
```

## Console/SSH (again)

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

## For the Googlers: errors on my way

Show logs with

```
drush ws --count=100 --extended --tail
# or cd into `<DRUPALFOLDER>` and do
php drush.phar ws --count=100 --extended --tail
```

►►►

```
 *****  24/Aug **:**  update    error     GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: Error creating resource: [message]
                                          fopen(http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x?site_key=****************************
                                          ***************&version=8.5.6&list=**********************************************************...
                                          ...*************************************************************************): failed to open
                                          stream: Connection timed out
                                          [file] /var/www/html/******************/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
                                          [line] 324 in GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::wrapException() (line 52 of
                                          /var/www/html/******************/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php).
 *****  24/Aug **:**  update    error     GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: Error creating resource: [message]
                                          fopen(http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/admin_toolbar/8.x?site_key=*********************
                                          ***************************************&list=admin_toolbar%2Cadmin_toolbar_tools): failed to
                                          open stream: Connection timed out
                                          [file] /var/www/html/******************/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
                                          [line] 324 in GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::wrapException() (line 52 of
                                          /var/www/html/******************/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php).
```

►►►

```
 *****  24/Aug **:**  notic  user  Session opened for ***.
                      e
 *****  24/Aug **:**  error  upda  GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET
                             te    http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/admin_toolbar/8.x?site_key=**********************************
                                   *********&version=8.x-1.24&list=admin_toolbar%2Cadmin_toolbar_tools` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`
                                   response:



 *****  24/Aug **:**  error  upda  GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET
                             te    http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x?site_key=*****************************************
                                   **&version=8.5.6&list=******************************************************************************...
                                   ...***************************` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
```